# One line of short Os.Walk code fails me

Tags: python

I just want to change files names in an Entire Directory. Code is solid for single directories with os.listdir but when I moved up to os.walk it failed me.

```
import os

rootFolder = "C:/Users/.../Desktop/Docs"

for folder in os.walk(rootFolder):
    for filename in folder:
        os.rename(filename, filename[4:])
```

Last line gives me an error *"The system cannot find the path specified"*  Can anyone please help me out? So close...

Comment: os.walk generates 3-tuples of form (dirpath, dirnames, filenames), so you're folder var is really a 3-tuple --  see https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk

Comment: @lemonhead Ok I followed up on that Link and understand the 3 tuples var now.  But the situation still eludes me.  Sorry I'm new to this language and on what to do about the last line.  'os.remove(os.path.join(filename, filename[12:]))' was my subsequent attempt .

Comment: hmm, I'm a little confused as to what you are trying to do then... are you trying to remove all files, strip off the first 4 characters of each filename, do something with the first 12 characters? Might help to clarify in your question or give an example of how the filenames should be changed...

Comment: Roger that, sorry I made a mistake in my last response.  Ignore that [12:] it was supposed to be [4:].  Simply put, I'm just trying to recursively go through every folder and strip off the first 4 characters off the filenames.  Examples: 'JOB Park St' = 'Park St'; 'JOB Ford Property' = 'Ford Property'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the full pathname to those files, your code will work. You can get the full pathname from `os.walk` if you combine the `dirpath` with the `filename`. Here's how:

```
import os

root_folder = "C:/Users/.../Desktop/Docs"

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(root_folder):
    for fname in filenames:
        full_fname = os.path.join(dirpath, fname)
        renamed = os.path.join(dirpath, fname[4:])
        os.rename(full_fname, renamed)
```

It is important to use the full pathname to the renamed file as well. Otherwise the files will be moved to the directory from which you're running the Python interpreter.

Note that in the third line of code, I'm using *[tuple unpacking](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences)* (or sequence unpacking, as the docs call it).

Comment: Works for me, Thanks!  And yeah... I was sniffing close to os.path after what lemonhead suggested, but no way was I going to figure out to use dirpath.  And I thought if you used os.path.join that meant my fname would append the directory name to my new fname.  But all you're doing is TELLING it where to look.  Nice again and THANKS to lemonhead and You for looking at my problem! Total geniuses